# Is it possible to express the "type of functions that receive 2 nats and return their sum"?

Tags: haskell, types, agda, dependent-type, idris

Given the following types:

```
CNat : Type
CNat = (a:Type) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a

add : CNat -> CNat -> CNat
add x y t s z = x t s (y t s z)
```

Is it possible to express the "type of functions that receive two nats, `x` and `y`, and return another nat `z`, such that `add x y == z`?

Comment: So that would be the type whose only member is `add`?

Comment: It's certainly easy to do with inductively defined nats. You can even do it in Haskell. Are you particularly attached to Church numerals? If so, I recommend becoming unattached to them.

Comment: @leftroundabout That would depend on how intensional we're being. Idris and Agda allow the definition of highly intensional properties, e.g., the type whose only member is *that implementation* of `add`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout how so? If you reorder the arguments (`add x y t s z = y t s (x t s z)`) you still have that `add x y == add y z`, but that is a different function.

Comment: @pigworker numbers are either church encoded, scott encoded or primitives... primitives hide all the hard work through syntax sugars, so, if you want to learn what is under the hoods, then there aren't many options, right?

Comment: What's your notion of equality? [Here](http://lpaste.net/288742) are four variants.

Comment: @Viclib I'm not sure I see why the specific representation matters, actually... What about just `plus : (n : CNat) -> (m : CNat) -> (r : CNat ** r = add n m)`? It seems like that sort of thing should work regardless of the representation.

Comment: @DavidYoung Because propositional equality isn't extensional. At least, not in Idris

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I was wondering about that right after I commented actually, but Idris seems to accept this type with the definition `plus n m = (add n m ** Refl)`. Maybe its because you end up with a syntactic equality with that specific definition if you expand it out though?

Comment: @Viclib, what caused you to believe such falsehoods? Inductively defined numbers have an *induction principle*; Church-encoded numbers, per se, do not. They're not the same thing. And if you want to use types depending on numbers, you need induction, not just iteration. The idea that Church-encoded data are just like actual data is popular, but deeply unhelpful.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yes, I think it's just alpha-comparing `add n m` with `add n m`. Try flipping the arguments! You can't prove `add n m = add m n` for Church numerals with propositional equality, cos you don't know anything about `n` and `m`.

Comment: @pigworker, I have not, sadly, been able to find an explanation of the word "intensional" that I can understand. Do you think you could help? For the type in question, do you mean something like `isMyAdd f = (f = myAdd)`?

Comment: @pigworker what the heck are you talking about? Whatever you think I "claimed" about datatypes is wrong. Re-read my comment, all I said is that using built-in primitive datatypes wouldn't allow me to see the actual underlying expressions because Idris has so many layers of syntax sugars that it is hard (for me) to map the high-level syntax to the core calculus. That is why I chose the church encoding and there is no more to it than that.

Comment: @dfeuer Intensional equality is one which does not admit extensionality, i.e. `∀ x . f x = g x  ==> f = g`, and without this it is very hard to produce a proof that any `CNat` is equal to any other. @Viclib That is precisely your issue, the lack of extensionality, so you will need to define a proper equivalence for `CNat` or use inductive naturals (as already stated). You seem to want to avoid 'primitive' numerals (i.e. machine words?) but nobody is suggesting you use those - `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` is not 'primitive' and has no syntactic sugar involved.

Comment: @user2407038 it is a syntax, I'm often interested in understanding how those things map to a core calculus, i.e., just lambdas, foralls, vars, etc.

Comment: @Viclib Read your own comment. It makes a rather prescriptive false statement about the possible encodings of numbers, and then appears to presume incorrectly the equivalence of those encodings.

Comment: @pigworker *"seems to presume the equivalence"* - that is not on my comment, it didn't even cross my mind. I don't even know what equivalence means in that context. Again, I said those are the 3 ways I know how to encode datatypes, and the church-encoding makes it easier to translate what I'm doing on Idris to a simpler core such as Morte.

Comment: "intensional" means "characteristic of the implementation"; "extensional" means "characteristic of the observable behaviour"; so mergeSort is extensionally equal to and intensionally different from bubbleSort.

Comment: @Viclib It can only be "simpler" because it achieves less. Moreover, higher-order encodings of first-order things count as simplifications only in a world that is entirely on its head.

Comment: @Viclib It is not just a syntax - inductive datatypes (and generalizations of such) are given formal semantics just as lambdas, foralls, etc are given them. Yes, there are equivalent formulizations of the things we do with inductive datatypes, but just the same all these systems of computation are 'equivalent' because they are turing complete. Why are you not attempting to model this in terms of a universal turing machine, which is much more 'simple', or 'fundamental' than any other formalism for computation? (answer: you pick the tool for the job, which is what makes your life easiest)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're arguing for, but the introduction on [this](https://fermat.github.io/document/papers/rta-tlca.pdf) paper explains most of the reasons I think it is valuable to have a simpler core language and to understand concepts w.r.t that core. It also proposes self types which give the induction principle you mentioned.